What is the density of gravitons at the surface of the earth?
The Earth is moving along a geodesic trajectory influenced by the mass and position of the Sun (ignoring other bodies in the solar system). What does this actually translate into, in terms of gravitons (or density of gravitons) at the surface of the Earth? I assume the frequency of the gravitons is related to the orbital frequency of the Sun-Earth system.
The mass of the Earth also influences everything in its vicinity. It causes the Moon to orbit, objects to fall to the ground, and pressure inside the Earth itself. Hence, the Earth itself must be a big, spherically-symmetric graviton generator. What is the density of gravitons at the surface of the Earth due to the Earth’s mass alone (and also due to the additional kinetic energy of the Earth spinning on its axis)? Ignoring the Earth’s spin, what would be the frequency of the gravitons emitted by a static body?

I suspect you are thinking that a gravitational field is built up from gravitons, but this is not the case. The graviton is the quantum of the gravitational wave and to a good approximation the Earth Sun system is not emitting any gravitational waves (strictly speaking it is emitting GWs but with a vanishingly low intensity).

We can in principle write the gravitational field as a sum of virtual gravitons, but these virtual particles are just a computational device and do not exist. So the density of (non-virtual) gravitons at the Earth's surface is zero.

What idiots downvote an honest question but don’t comment or answer?

Hi Khun. I'm not a fan of anonymous downvotes either, but note that they are not meant to be a personal criticism. Downvotes are just an indicator that the question is not a useful one. In this case the question cannot be answered for the reasons I explained above. You need to clarify what you are asking for us to say anything useful.

Also have a look at the question Sun-Earth Virtual Gravitons? as it related.

The sun-earth system has a period of 1 y and consequently a basic wavelength for any form of massless radiation fields of 1 ly, rouhgly the extension of the solar  system.
Any form of abstractly formulated energy-monentum density flow in an steadily oscillating system  inside the near field sphere is meaningless.
Remind that the concept of 'energy'  is of purely  mathematical origin: in Newtons equation by change of $x'^2$ and in wave physics by change of $\nabla f^2$. What causes radiation to infinity are the boundary conditions of large spheres by the chaos of source motion and near fields in its interior.
To turn the question around to 'how reacts the source to the  radiation condition on a large sphere is the source of QFT.
